# Listings adds whitespaces, how to remove it?

Tags: latex, whitespace, listings

Hey guys,
when using listings to present code in my PDF, it adds whitespaces after some characters.
[This is how it looks in the pdf](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12519690/problem) (I'm not allowed to post images because of reputation, 'hence add ".png" to the url, sorry).

I'm using the following code to add the listings.

```
\newcommand{\lstchange}[2]{
  \lstset{breaklines=true,
  frame=single,
  captionpos=b,
  basicstyle={\ttfamily\footnotesize},
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  numberstyle={\ttfamily\footnotesize},
  keywordstyle={\bfseries\color{blue}},
  stringstyle=\color{darkorange}\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen},
  language=#1,
  morekeywords={#2} }
}

% ...

\lstchange{bash}{svn , cd, gnome-open}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=someCaption, label=someLabel]
#!/bin/bash

svn checkout http://opendecisionrepository.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sources/web-interface/src/main/webapp odr-appetizer-2 -r 621

cd odr-appetizer-2

#open drawing.xhtml
gnome-open drawing.xhtml
\end{lstlisting}
```

Does anyone of you have an idea why this happens? Even if I use the standard example from the latex wikibook this happens.

Maybe this is also important for you, the config file:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\usepackage{%
  array,
  booktabs,
  dcolumn,
  rotating,
  shortvrb,
  tabularx,
  units,
  url,
  xcolor,
  lastpage,
  longtable,
  lscape,
  multirow,
  amssymb,
  amsmath,
  float,
  chngpage,
  colortbl,
  helvet,
  listings
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

Ben

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site, where no TeX-related question is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce this here (with `\documentclass{article}`), it looks fine. I only had to comment out "OliveGreen" because it was unknown.